# FileUpload with Custom Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having an issue with fileupload that is being validated by a custom validator.  The textbox value is always empty or null onververvalidate.

ASPX

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvFileUpload" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Please select file!" ControlToValidate="fuCheatingEvidence" 
                onservervalidate="cvFileUpload_ServerValidate" 
                ValidationGroup="vgSubmitForm" ValidateEmptyText="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fuCheatingEvidence" runat="server" 
                 Width="890px" Size="50" />
```

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void cvFileUpload_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    String fileName = fuCheatingEvidence.PostedFile.FileName;

    if (fileName != "")
    {
        args.IsValid = true;

    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }

}
```

It's just a simple check to see if the FileUpload control is empty or not and later on I will add some more custom validation.

Comment: I've also used the if(fuCheatingEvidence.HasFile) but that returns false eventhough there is a file on the FileUpload control.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and it works just fine.
When adding a file I get both the `hasFile` and the `fileName`

```
protected void cvFileUpload_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    bool hasFile = fuCheatingEvidence.HasFile; // Returns true
    String fileName = fuCheatingEvidence.PostedFile.FileName; // Returns the filename
     .....
}
```

This leads me to belive that you have some other part of your code that is causing problems. I recommend creating a side project with only the `FileUpload` and the `CustomValidator` and see for yourself that it works. Then, try to figure out what is causing the problems in your main project. If you still have problems ask another question which is specific to the real problem that you have.

Comment: Thanks, I think what's causing the issue is that I have an UpdatePanel in a small part of the entire page but I have that UpdatePanel set to UpdateMode="Conditional".  So, the fix that I did was to encapsulate everything in the UpdatePanel and add a trigger to do a full-autopostback.  However, I thought there was an issue with FileUpload controls being in UpdatePanels.